# What would be a sensible way of looking at the distributions of 2 continuous variables and a categorical variable on the same plot?

Tags: r, math, plot, statistics

In R, if I have 2 continuous variables and 1 categorical variable, what is a sensible way of plotting all of these on the same plot? For example, let's say my 2 continuous variables were the height and weight of people and my categorical variable was race, in what way could I graph these using histograms, etc. so that I could view their distributions on the same plot and make some sort of comparison? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Plots of the distribution of two variables on one plot are usually called *marginal histogram* or *marginal density* plots, so that's a useful search term.

One way to plot marginal densities by group is using `ScatterHistC` from the `WVPlots` package.

```
library(WVPlots)

ScatterHistC(iris, "Sepal.Length", "Petal.Length", "Species", title = "Petal length vs Sepal length")
```

[image]

You could also try [this function](https://github.com/ChrKoenig/R_marginal_plot).

Answer (score 0):

Does this get you started?

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(Height = c(70,65,72,71),Weight = c(150,110,220,310),Race = c("White","Black","Black","White" ))


t <- ggplot(df, aes(Height,Weight)) + geom_point()
t + facet_grid(Race ~.)
```

[image: Sample Plot]

Or...

```
ggplot(df, aes(Height,Weight)) + geom_point(size = 5,aes(color = factor(Race)))
```

[image]